# How to assign Tags to all VMs only in a resource group using Azure cli

Tags: azure, tags, virtual-machine, command-line-interface

I am trying to write an Azure CLI script that logs me into the portal using service principal, selects the subscription and then tag VMs in that subscription per Resource group only.

```
az login -u $service_principal_ID -p $service_principal_password --service-principal --tenant $tenant_ID

az account set --subscription $subID

az resource tag --resource-group $rg \
--tags tags.project=$project tags.owner=$owner tags.environment=$env \
--resource-type "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" \
--output tsv
```

Azure gives me error when running this saying `--name` is missing, but I don't want to tag the VMs one by one.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this (I don't need any resources tagging ;) )

but something like this should get you working.

Basically, you need to pass that named parameter, and the only way to do that is to parse through the VM list first.

```
sample=$(az vm list --resource-group $rg )
for row in $(echo "${sample}" | jq -r '.[] | @base64'); do
    _jq() {
    echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
    }

VMName=$(_jq '.name')

az resource tag --resource-group $rg \
--tags tags.project=$project tags.owner=$owner tags.environment=$env \
--resource-type "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines" \
--name $VMName \
--output tsv

done
```

Entirely unrelated, and this should probably be edited out  - but damn, I do miss how easy this stuff is in PowerShell.

Comment: I tried this and it gets stuck. I have a resource group with about 6 VMs, it only tags the first 2 then gets stuck on #2. FYI, I am using Jenkins to automate this.

Comment: @fumes007 that is difficult to answer without further information, it is probably worth creating another question, and refer to this one, show the code you're using, and any error messages  - all that jazz

Answer (score 0):

**Add desired tags to the resource group:**

```
az group update -n $rg \
--set tags.project=$project tags.owner=$owner tags.environment=$env
```

**Then apply all the tags from that resource group to each child resource:**

```
do
  jsontag=$(az group show -n $rg --query tags)
  t=$(echo $jsontag | tr -d '"{},' | sed 's/: /=/g')
  r=$(az resource list -g $rg --query [].id --output tsv)
  for resid in $r
  do
    az resource tag --tags $t --id $resid
  done
done
```

Comment: Based on this, I see it assigns tags to all resources in the RG?

Comment: @fumes007 - Yep! Is that not what you were asking for?

Comment: I want to tag VMs in the RG only and stop/restart those VMs based on the tag(s) I specified. 

sample script to stop/start

`az vm deallocate --ids $(az resource list --tag Restart=$TAG_RESTART --query "[?type=='Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines'].id" -o tsv)`

I also want to output the report to a excel spreadsheet

Comment: @fumes007 - Yes, that code snippet that I posted will add tags to all resources within an RG. So just add that to your script and you will be good to go.